# Error running a command from Dockerfile, but runs fine from the container

Tags: python, docker, torch

I'm setting up a docker image for the OneFormer ML model ([environment instructions here](https://github.com/SHI-Labs/OneFormer/blob/main/INSTALL.md)).

The Dockerfile that I have works, except for the very last command:

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:11.3.1-devel-ubuntu20.04

# Set environment variables
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ENV LANG=C.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL=C.UTF-8

# Update package list and install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    wget \
    ca-certificates \
    git \
    build-essential \
    libglib2.0-0 \
    libsm6 \
    libxext6 \
    libxrender1 \
    libyaml-cpp-dev \
    libopencv-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install GCC, G++ 9
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    gcc-9 \
    g++-9 \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-9 100 \
    && update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-9 100

# Install conda 4.12.0
RUN wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-py38_4.12.0-Linux-x86_64.sh -O miniconda.sh \
    && chmod +x miniconda.sh \
    && ./miniconda.sh -b -p /opt/conda \
    && rm miniconda.sh \
    && /opt/conda/bin/conda clean -tipsy \
    && ln -s /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh /etc/profile.d/conda.sh \
    && echo ". /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" >> ~/.bashrc \
    && echo "conda activate base" >> ~/.bashrc

# Set some environment variables
ENV PATH /opt/conda/bin:$PATH
ENV WANDB_API_KEY=...
ENV CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda
ENV FORCE_CUDA=1

# Clone OneFormer repository and set working directory
RUN git clone https://github.com/SHI-Labs/OneFormer.git /OneFormer
WORKDIR /OneFormer

# Install dependencies
RUN conda install pytorch==1.10.1 torchvision==0.11.2 cudatoolkit=11.3 -c pytorch -c conda-forge
RUN pip3 install -U opencv-python
RUN python -m pip install detectron2 -f https://dl.fbaipublicfiles.com/detectron2/wheels/cu113/torch1.10/index.html
RUN pip3 install git+https://github.com/cocodataset/panopticapi.git
RUN pip3 install git+https://github.com/mcordts/cityscapesScripts.git
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
# RUN pip3 install wandb
# RUN wandb login

# Setup MSDeformAttn
# RUN cd oneformer/modeling/pixel_decoder/ops && \
#     sh ./make.sh

# Set the default command to run when starting the container
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

When it gets to the `# Setup MSDeformAttn` block I get this error:

```
#0 13.59 cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
#0 15.97 /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py:381: UserWarning: Attempted to use ninja as the BuildExtension backend but we could not find ninja.. Falling back to using the slow distutils backend.
#0 15.97   warnings.warn(msg.format('we could not find ninja.'))
#0 15.97 Traceback (most recent call last):
#0 15.97   File "setup.py", line 69, in <module>
#0 15.97     setup(
#0 15.97   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup
#0 15.97     return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
#0 15.97   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
#0 15.97     dist.run_commands()
#0 15.97   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
#0 15.97     self.run_command(cmd)
#0 15.97   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
#0 15.97     cmd_obj.run()
#0 15.97   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
#0 15.97     self.run_command(cmd_name)
#0 15.97   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
#0 15.97     self.distribution.run_command(command)
#0 15.97   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
#0 15.97     cmd_obj.run()
#0 15.97   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 79, in run
#0 15.97     _build_ext.run(self)
#0 15.97   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Cython/Distutils/old_build_ext.py", line 186, in run
#0 15.97     _build_ext.build_ext.run(self)
#0 15.97   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 340, in run
#0 15.97   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 202, in build_extension
#0 15.97     _build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
#0 15.97   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 528, in build_extension
#0 15.97     objects = self.compiler.compile(sources,
#0 15.97   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 574, in compile
#0 15.97     self._compile(obj, src, ext, cc_args, extra_postargs, pp_opts)
#0 15.97   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 483, in unix_wrap_single_compile
#0 15.97     cflags = unix_cuda_flags(cflags)
#0 15.97   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 450, in unix_cuda_flags
#0 15.97     cflags + _get_cuda_arch_flags(cflags))
#0 15.97   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 1606, in _get_cuda_arch_flags
#0 15.97     arch_list[-1] += '+PTX'
#0 15.97 IndexError: list index out of range
------
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c cd oneformer/modeling/pixel_decoder/ops &&     sh ./make.sh]: exit code: 1
```

But when I comment out this command, start the container and do this:

```
cd oneformer/modeling/pixel_decoder/ops
bash make.sh
```

It builds without errors and the demo code runs. What could be the reason that it refuses to run from the dockerfile? The error message isn't very helpful.

Comment: Try setting `SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-l", "-c"]` early, e.g., after your `ENV` directives. The error shows that `sh -c` is used, but Conda only is initialized with interactive bash (as per `.bashrc`).